# Next-auth signin redirects to /signin?csrf=true

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next-auth

i have implemented next-auth as in documentation ,when i go to http://localhost:3001/api/auth/signin, i see this
[image]

after this when i click signin with google or github , i page refrshes and just gets redirected to **http://localhost:3001/api/auth/signin?csrf=true** nothing happens after that. its the same page.

my [...nextauth.js] file

```
    import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import Providers from "next-auth/providers";

export default NextAuth({
    providers: [
        Providers.Google({
            clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT,
            clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_KEY,
        }),
        Providers.GitHub({
            clientId: process.env.GITHUB_CLIENT,
            clientSecret: process.env.GITHUB_SECRET,
        }),
    ],
});
```

any idea , why is it not working

i thing it has something to do with my node-express server
the code for that is

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const server = require("http").createServer(app);
const next = require("next");
const nextApp = next({ dev: true });
const nextHandler = nextApp.getRequestHandler();


/*******************ROUTES****************/
const userRoutes = require("./server/routes/user");

nextApp.prepare().then(() => {
    app.use("/node/user", userRoutes);
    app.all("*", (req, res) => nextHandler(req, res));
    server.listen(3001, err => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("> ---------Server is ready on port 3001------------");
    });
});
```

Comment: I've got this problem too, it seems that next-auth doesn't work well with express.js, are you using a custom server?

Comment: yap, using a custom server. I ended up using a passport with express

Comment: I'm using the default server and have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had something similar, also using a custom express server. Looking in `next-auth/dist/server/index.js` you end up hitting that redirect whenever `csrfTokenVerified` is false. In my case, the csrf token was being sent with the `signin/[provider]` request. I think that the client was sending the request body urlencoded, and this was not parsed by the express server so never made it is as far as the next auth server endpoints. I fixed it using node package `bodyparser` and adding this line to my express server setup `app.use(urlencoded({ extended: true }));`. I didn't have this problem with next v9, but did with newer releases.